# Error message: wkernelbase.pdb not loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I working with VS2013 and had an error "Unhandled exception at 0x76B74598 in Project1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0112B50C". When I click "break", it shown that "wkernelbase.pdb not loaded" "wkernelbase.pdb contain the debug information required to find the source for the module KernelBase.dll"

I had tried some solution suggested and one of them is Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols and select check in a box "Microsoft Symbol Servers", mark load all modules then click Load all Symbols. But I can't mark load all modules.

Any other solution to fixed this error and load the file by manual?

Comment: you can't get private debug symbols from ms

Comment: then, any suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not as good as to answer here. But this answer might be helpful.

For this error you have to look into your code and debug again. You don't have to load pdb externally or explicitly. Try one of these possible solution given below:

- You probably trying to display image but image is actually not loaded
  in memory.
- You are missing any header file of opencv and calling    their
  functions in your code.

Thank You :)